# Round My number?

Tags: php

Round My number?

I have an number

```
$n = -5665.36
$round_set = can be : 1,10,10,100,1000
```

use the $round_set condition to get the $m

if $round_set = 1

```
  $m = $n
```

if $round_set = 10

```
$m = -5660
```

if $round_set = 100

```
  $m = -5600
```

if $round_set = 1000

```
  $m = -5000
```

Anybody know how to round these kind of case?

Comment: There is a certain inconsistency with the way you use $roundset. I'd expect 0 to return a whole number, not a decimal part. Its not a problem of course, just might confuse others looking at this code (or you in 6 months time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://codepad.viper-7.com/1EHFWEJ](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1EHFWE) test it here.

```
<?php
$n = -5665.36;
$round_set = 100;
$precision =  -log10($round_set);
$m = ($round_set == 1 ? $n : round($n, $precision) + $round_set);
echo $m;
?>
```

Comment: what is difference between you and @Gaurav?

Comment: using intval is shorter ;-) but when you use Gaurav's solution you need to add an exception for $roundset = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
intval($m/$round_set) * $round_set
```

Comment: Look my case if $round_set = 100 I want 5600 not 5700 like you did here

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
function rounded_nb($number, $round_set) {
    return floor($number/$round_set)*$round_set;
}
```

For any non 0 $round_set ?

Comment: Look my case if $round_set = 100 I want 5600 not 5700 like you did here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the switch, do

```
if($round_set > 0) {
  $rounded = $round_set * floor($n / $round_set);
} else {
  $rounded = $n;
}
```

This should pretty much do.

Comment: You're missing some bits. in the first part of the if you need to multiply by $round_set again to get back to the right order of magnitude. And in the second return $n, not 0.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I guess I shouldn't write posts in hurry :)

Comment: look my case if $round_set = 100 I want 5600 not 5700 like you did here

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs1 = max(1, $round_set);
$m = $rs1 * floor($n / $rs1);
```

However a 1,10,100,... valued `$round_set` might make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

Why not take advantage of PHP's `round`

```
$m = round($n, ($round_set == 0 ? 0 : -1 * log10($round_set)) );
```

**Edit**: Corrected edge-case of `log10(0)`.

**Edit 2**: Corrected the precision.

Comment: +1 for mentioning this option; -1 for not being able to use round as the requirement is to round the number to `ceil` if it's negative. -5665 (with round_set 100) would round to 5700 if I'm not wrong.; -1 for not including minus (-log10($round_set))

Comment: I had already corrected the lack of a negative long before you commented. But yes, it would round to -5700, should have paid more attention.

Comment: look my case if $round_set = 100 I want 5600 not 5700 like you did here

Comment: @stackunderflow: I'm aware of the mistake.